# React-nvd3 show multiple lines on line chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying out react-nvd3.js, and I have no problem rendering a line chart with a single series. However, I am not sure on how to render with multiple series on the same chart (same axis).

I know that my data is in the correct format since the chart will render one series (the first series). The option to show/hide the two series does appear correctly. I am guessing adjusting the `y="value_1"` should do the trick, but have so far not been successful.

my data:

```
    datum = [
       {
          values: series_1,
          key: 'value_1',
       },{
          values: series_2,
          key: 'value_2',
       }
    ];
```

and my rendering:

```
    <NVD3Chart id="lineWithFocusChart" type="lineWithFocusChart" datum={datum} x="label" y="value_1"/>,
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a problem with how you are referencing the dataset to the x and y axis.

Try changing your attributes to
`x='key'` and `y='values'`

```
<NVD3Chart id="lineWithFocusChart" type="lineWithFocusChart" datum={datum} x="key" y="values"/>
```